# Feynman diagram for two-dimensional nonlinear sigma model with antisymmetric coupling

Tags: string-theory, feynman-diagrams, quantum-gravity, sigma-models

I am studying the review by C. Calland and L. Thorlacius (link: https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/sigma.pdf) on sigma models in string theory. In particular I am trying to evaluate the Feynman diagram in figure 3.2 on page 32 and I have some trouble in writing down the corresponding integral. For my particular question it is not necessary to understand further details from the paper but let me just introduce a couple of important equations.

The antisymmetric tensor action is
$$
S_{AS}[X_0+\pi] - S_{AS}[X_0] = \frac{1}{4\pi\alpha'}\int d^2\xi\epsilon^{ab}\partial_aX^{\mu}\partial_bX^{\nu}B_{\mu\nu}.
$$
Up to quadratic order in the quantum field $\eta^i$ one obtains the covariant expression (see page 27-28 for details but not essential for the rest)
$$
S_{AS}[X_0+\pi] - S_{AS}[X_0] = \frac{1}{4\pi\alpha'}\int d^2\xi\epsilon^{ab} [H_{\mu ij}(X_0)\partial_aX_0^{\mu}\partial_b\eta^i\eta^j + \frac{1}{2}\nabla_iH_{\mu\nu j}(X_0)\partial_aX_0^{\mu}\partial_bX_0^{\nu}\eta^i\eta^j],
$$
where we have assumed a flat worldsheet so $\nabla_a\rightarrow\partial_a$.

From this final expression we can read off two possible vertices that give rise to the two diagrams in figures 3.2 and 3.3 in the paper. My question is about the one in figure 3.2 with the two $\epsilon^{ab}H_{\mu ij}\partial_aX_0^{\mu}\partial_b\eta^i\eta^j$ vertices:

[image]

The cross denotes an insertion of the $++$ component of the classical energy-momentum tensor $\partial_+\eta^i\partial_+\eta^i$ from the Polyakov action. In the figure I've denoted the momentum of the internal propagators, the external ones together carry away the inserted momentum by the energy-momentum tensor.

The internal propagators are the quantum fields $\eta^i$ and the external fields are the bosonic, background fields $X_0^{\mu}$. In the expressions above some target space indices are referred to a local Lorentz frame using a vielbein, see the paper for more details on that if you wish.

I would like to write down the loop momentum integral corresponding to this expression and by looking at the action above we can read off what the expressions are for the vertices in momentum space. I obtain the following expression
$$
\int\frac{d^2 l}{2\pi}\frac{l_+^2(l_++q_+)^2(l+q+k)_c(l+q+k)_d}{l^2(l+q)^2(l+q+k)^2}\{H^2_{\mu\nu}(X_0)\partial_aX_0^{\mu}\partial_bX_0^{\nu}\epsilon^{ac}\epsilon^{bd}\}(q,k)
$$
where $H^2_{\mu\nu}(X_0)=H_{\mu\lambda\sigma}(X_0)H_{\nu}^{\,\lambda\sigma}(X_0)$.

**Question** How does one evaluate this momentum integral? And is it the correct expression?

Comment: Any news? Well...in any case i can cite to you this [master thesis](https://repositorio.unesp.br/bitstream/handle/11449/132536/000854703.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y).